# $geoWithin for a point returns empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have stored locations in my documents according to the [Mongo Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/geospatial-queries/) but I can't seem to really put it in action. I have tried `$geoWithin` as well as `$near` but It doesn't work. It just outputs an empty array. I have also checked my indexes and they are being made perfectly.

Here's my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: [true,'Please enter a title for the item']
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point']
          },
          coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
          }
    }
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model('Items',ItemSchema);
```

The controller method for getting the items' information is:

```
// @desc      Get all items
// @route     GET /api/items/:lat/:lon/:distance
// @access    Private
exports.getItems = asyncHandler( async (req, res, next) => {
  const { lat, lon, distance } = req.params;

  // Calc radius using radians
  // Divide dist by radius of Earth
  // Earth Radius = 3,963.2 mi / 6,378 km
  const radius = distance / 3963.2;

  const items = await Item.find({
      location: {
        $geoWithin:{
          $centerSphere: [
            [lon, lat],
            radius
          ]
        }
      }
    });

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    count: items.length,
    data: items
  });
});
```

But it returns only this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "count": 0,
    "data": []
}
```

Some sample data that I'm looking to get back is:

```
"success": true,
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    33.699345,
                    73.043875
                ]
            },
            "_id": "633755fb88bd5df5363610d5",
            "title": " inoobbiibiib",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    33.714056,
                    73.023514
                ]
            },
            "_id": "633930779c771beb4a0fc8e6",
            "title": "jyjkymymhh",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

And I am hitting that route from Postman with this:
[image: Postman]

`lat` and `lon` are the variables that hold co-ordinates of my current location.

Comment: Do you have the sample document that you are expecting to match along with the predicate values that the app is querying with?

Comment: I will edit the post to include that too

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure if that's what you asked for since I am new to this but I've edited the post. If you could have any feedback regarding that, it'd be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share values for lat, long and distance, you are using?

Comment: `lat: 73.05302350472694`,
`lon: 33.69672730400787`,
`distance: 10`, which would then be divided by Earth's radius to make a searching area/radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O_T27fqTChq) seems to demonstrate the query with the given sample data and predicate values correctly returning the results. The predicate values (`lat: 73.05302350472694, lon: 33.69672730400787, distance: 10`) come from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73928946/geowithin-for-a-point-returns-empty?noredirect=1#comment130542088_73928946), with the `distance` having the radian conversion from the code applied (`10 / 3963.2`).

I'm not an expert, but I'm curious if the `lon` and `lat` parameters have been inadvertently swapped.  From the screenshot, the `GET` request hits:

```
{{LOCAL}}/api/items/{{lon}}/{{lat}}/10
```

But in the handler code I see:

```
// @route     GET /api/items/:lat/:lon/:distance
// @access    Private
exports.getItems = asyncHandler( async (req, res, next) => {
  const { lat, lon, distance } = req.params;
```

Does ordering matter when these variables are being processed? I'm assuming so, which means that the Postman request has the two variables in the wrong order.  That would certainly explain why the query is failing to return results.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for bringing my attention to that. But I found that the request route I was hitting was the real culprit as I am doing `/{{lon}}/{{lat}}/10` but the route is set as `/:lat/:lon/:distance`. Really silly of me

Comment: That's what I was trying to point out in my answer. Glad to see that this got sorted, happy coding!